# Retrieve line number from LeakTraceElement

Tags: java, memory-leaks, stack-trace, line-numbers, leakcanary

I am using [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to detect memory leaks. In order to track events I convert the `LeakTraceElement` into a `StackTraceElement` as indicated in ["LeakCanary, then what? Nuking Nasty Memory Leaks by Pierre-Yves Ricau"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7A7Uv9ZBE2U&t=17m04s).

[image: Code snippet]

I would like to pass the line number to the `StackTraceElement` constructor:

```
StackTraceElement(String cls, String method, String file, int line) { /* ... */ }
```

How can I retrieve the **line number** form LeakCanary?

Answer (score 0):

I just played with this a bit and after doing some more digging it looks like that information is not directly available at runtime.

[How to get line number of an instance variable from a java object during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823761/how-to-get-line-number-of-an-instance-variable-from-a-java-object-during-runtime)