# Order YAML file entries according to its java equivalent class (SnakeYaml)

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am using SnakeYaml to both load/dump data in Java. For this I have created a custom class with fields, say that the class looks something like this:

```
public class Person {
        private String name;
        private String lastName;
        private String address;
        
        public Person() {
            // Do nothing
        }
        
        // Getters and setters initialized for all the fields
    }
```

Now, what I would like is that when I write a Person object to a file with SnakeYaml I would want to have the fields in the order they are defined in the class.

e.g.

```
name: Patrick
lastName: Star
Age : 42
```

The problem is that for more advanced examples, this ordering is **not** achieved. Currently I am writing/dumping to a yaml file like the following:

```
Constructor struct = new Constructor(YamlIteratorModel.class);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(struct);

try {
   String path = "Some/File/Path/yamlfile.yaml";
   FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path);
   yaml.dump(iteratorModel, writer);
} catch (IOExcepton e) {
   // Do something
}
```

What I have also tried is creating a **Representer** class which extends Representer and calls the Yaml constructor in a similar manner. This one is taken from another post, and it doesn't do the job for me as it only sorts the Properties in an order I am not entirely sure of (can't find the link right now but will update if I find it again)..

```
public class ConfigurationModelRepresenter extends Representer {

    /**
     * Create object without specified dumper object
     */
    public ConfigurationModelRepresenter() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Create object with dumper options
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public ConfigurationModelRepresenter(DumperOptions options) {
        super(options);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    protected Set<Property> getProperties(Class< ? extends Object> type) {
        Set<Property> propertySet;
        if (typeDefinitions.containsKey(type)) {
            propertySet = typeDefinitions.get(type).getProperties();
        } else {
            propertySet = getPropertyUtils().getProperties(type);
        }

        List<Property> propsList = new ArrayList<>(propertySet);
        Collections.sort(propsList, new BeanPropertyComparator());

        return new LinkedHashSet<>(propsList);
    }

    class BeanPropertyComparator implements Comparator<Property> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Property p1, Property p2) {
            // p1.getType().get
            if (p1.getType().getCanonicalName().contains("util") && !p2.getType().getCanonicalName().contains("util")) {
                return 1;
            } else if (p2.getName().endsWith("Name") || p2.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SUMMARY**: How do I maintain the ordering when dumping an object to a YAML file (using SnakeYaml) e.g. the order the fields appear defined in the custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823761/how-to-get-line-number-of-an-instance-variable-from-a-java-object-during-runtime), which discusses that you cannot get the line number of a declared field via reflection.

Together with the fact that reflection gives you a classes' fields in [no particular order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()), it is obvious that it is not possible to observe the order of declared fields in a class at runtime, and it follows that you cannot order the keys in your YAML output according to their position/order in the source, because you cannot know that order.

The remedy is to transport the knowledge of the order to the runtime. Some possible ways to do this might be:

- Annotate each field with a `weight` that defines the position of the resulting YAML key (ugly because you need annotations on the fields).
- Autogenerate code by parsing the class' definition discovering the order from there, and write it to some autogenerated source file whose code is then used to order the properties in your Representer (this solution, while avoiding bloat in the original class, is very complex and elaborate).
- Hard-code the field order in the Representer. That's basically the previous solution but without autogenerating. Error-prone because the Representer must be adjusted each time the class is changed.

I recommend against using any of those solutions. The YAML spec specifically says that key order must not convey content information, and if the order is important to you, you are already violating the YAML spec and should switch to a format that better serves your needs.

Comment: I managed to get an order that kind of suits my needs using what I stated above but still not complete. However,  if it is as you say then I will have to circumvent this some other way. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

use this as your get properties function

```
    @Override
    protected Set<Property> getProperties(final Class<?> type) {
        // This is the order to output properties, other properties will not be output
        final List<String> order = List.of("name", "lastName", "address");
        final Set<Property> result = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> order.indexOf(a.getName())));
        result.addAll(super.getProperties(type)
                           .stream()
                           .filter(property -> order.contains(property.getName()))
                           .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        return result;
    }
```